# SpriteKit or Unity3d for racing track?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am a beginner with no prior gaming experience. I am planning to build an iPhone racing game in 2D using Sprite Kit. I want to use moving background (for racing track) like Highway rider or Rail Rush or subway surfer.

Can it be done in 2D by using Sprite Kit (without using Map editor like Tiled)?

Is Highway rider (or subway surfer or Rail Rush) a 3d Game? or it is 2d game but designed this way that it gives a feel of a 3d game.

Answer (score 0):

Subway Surfers is definitely a 3D game ; I don't know if that's the case for Rail Rush since I never played to this game, but from looking at screenshots on Google Images I would say so.

So if you want to achieve an effect that's similar to what you see in games such as Subway Surfers, you must go with a 3D Game Engine.

Now, what 3D engine ? Well, I think it's opinion based unless we have more details about what you want to do, but since you probably want to make a casual game without extremely advanced graphics (I mean, not graphics like in [FarCry 4](https://www.google.com/search?q=Crysis&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=10C7VLzMLszxUqjog9gP&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1240&bih=660#rls=en&tbm=isch&q=far+cry+4+screenshots&imgdii=_)), using Apple's Scene Kit seems a good idea to me.

EDIT : Oh, and sorry, I forgot to mention Unity3D, well, if you only want to choose between Sprite Kit and Unity3D, then Unity3D is the good choice since it's... 3D. But again, you should also consider other 3D engines, I don't know how exactly Unity3D is easy for beginners.

EDIT #2 : And because I spoke to you about Scene Kit, I think I should probably be giving you more details, first on the Apple website :

- [Introduction to Scene Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Scene Kit framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/) will give you a good idea of how to get started with Scene Kit, and you will be able to see all of the possibilities that it offers to you.

I think that what's good with Scene Kit is that the concepts that's at its core can be understood really easily, what I mean is that if you want to add, let's say, a cube, then you'll just set its position (by creating, positioning and adding a `SCNNode` to the scene) and then you'll attach a geometry to this specific node, this is this geometry that will be rendered on screen, for example if you want to make it a sphere, you will do something like that (in Swift) :

```
myNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius:0.5)
```

So you are able to add cameras, lights, objects that you create programmatically or that you load from Collada (.dae) or Alambic documents, the point of doing that is that you can create your object in a 3D tool such as Maya or Blender, and then simply import it to your game.
You can also add particle emitters (good to make smoke, rain, fire etc...), you have good customization possibilities on the materials too.

If you want to see what Scene Kit does in real life, you can try it by [downloading this on the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Introduction/Intro.html), it's a Scene Kit presentation of WWDC 2013 that's made... with Scene Kit, use the arrows to browse it.
It will run on your Mac but since 2014, Scene Kit also runs on iOS (and is nearly identical to what you'll find on your Mac). You can also take a look [at the presentation of 2014](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014551-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).
Hope my answer helps.